# NodeJS Amazon AWS SDK S3 client stops working intermittently

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have NodeJS express web server that serves files from AWS S3. Most of the time this exact code works correctly and serves files for a wide verity of applications with large numbers of requests in Production. The NodeJS web server is running across multiple nodes on a docker swarm server.

After about 2-3 weeks this stops working. There is no response from S3Client `GetObjectCommand`, there no error returned or anything. This starts working again only after restarting the NodeJS Docker container.

I read the S3 SDK docs that indicate a that the SDK will [retry automatically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html).

> Each AWS SDK implements automatic retry logic.

Questions:

- How can we make this code more resilient and not need a restart?
- Is the error handling correct? I'm wondering why there is no seemingly no response or error returned at all in this situation.
- Is it necessary to [configure the re-try settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-retry-behavior.html)?

NodeJS version: node:lts-alpine
Module: [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html)

Controllers

AWS Controller

```
const consoleLogger = require('../logger/logger.js').console;
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

const config = {
  "credentials": {
    "accessKeyId": "example",
    "secretAccessKey": "example"
  },
  "endpoint": "example",
  "sslEnabled": true,
  "forcePathStyle": true
}

const s3client = new S3Client(config);

const awsCtrl = {};

awsCtrl.getObject = async (key) => {

  // Get object from Amazon S3 bucket
  let data;
  try {
    // Data is returned as a ReadableStream
    data = await s3client.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: "example", Key: key }));
    console.log("Success", data);
  } catch (e) {
    consoleLogger.error("AWS S3 error: ", e);
    const awsS3Error = {
      name: e.name || null,
      status: e.$metadata.httpStatusCode || 500
    };
    throw awsS3Error;
  }

  return data;

}

module.exports = awsCtrl;
```

Files Controller

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
const consoleLogger = require('../logger/logger.js').console;
const httpCtrl = require('./http.ctrl');
const jwtCtrl = require('./jwt.ctrl');
const awsCtrl = require('./aws.ctrl');

filesCtrl.deliverFile = async (req, res) => {
  /* Get object from AWS S3 */
  let fileObjectStream;
  try {
    fileObjectStream = await awsCtrl.getObject(filePath);
  } catch (e) {
    consoleLogger.error(`Unable to get object from AWS S3`, e);
    if (e.status && e.status === 404) {
      result.error = `Not found`;
      result.status = 404;
      return res.status(result.status).json(result);
    }
    return res.status(e.status || 500).json(result);
  }

  const filename = lookupResponse.data.filename;

  // Set response header: Content-Disposition
  res.attachment(filename);
  // API response object stream download to client
  return fileObjectStream.Body.pipe(res);

}
```

API

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const filesCtrl = require('../../controllers/files.ctrl');
const filesValidation = require('../validation/files');

router.get('/:fileId', [filesValidation.getFile], (req, res, next) => {

  return filesCtrl.deliverFile(req, res);

});
```

Comment: As an aside, this could be a good use case for S3 signed URLs. Get your app server out of the business of proxying S3 content with all its overhead and offload that to S3 (or even CloudFront).

Comment: On the main issue, I'd guess some kind of resource leakage (file handles, sockets, etc.) over time building up. Wonder if you can identify this as an app bug or an AWS SDK bug or even a Docker bug with some high volume tests of each independently. May even be worth trying AWS SDK v2 if you have a good repro for this, in case it's a v3 SDK issue.

Comment: I have just started running into this since switching from knox to the v3 AWS SDK. It halts our image serving every 3-4 days until I restart the node process. Every call to GetObject just never returns. We don't use docker, and netstat doesn't show a freakish number of sockets. Given that the only change to our server code was to switch S3 library, I suspect AWS SDK, but no bugs have been filed about this and I can't reproduce it easily. Any more luck?

Comment: I recently encountered this and I posted my solution in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3560#issuecomment-1484140333. I hope it helps.